# BigQueryIO - Write to two tables for each item

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Apache Beam to write a job in Dataflow.
This job needs gets an input and transforms it into my custom object.
This object represents a memory test, which contains fixed properties like timestamp, name ... and a list of the partitions with their properties too

```
public class TestResult {

    String testName;
    String testId;
    String testStatus;
    String testResult;
    List<Partition> testPartitions;
}
public class Partition {
    String testId;
    String filesystem;
    String mountedOn;
    String usePercentage;
    String available;
    String size;
    String used;
}
```

My last transform, takes this TestResult Object and transforms it into Table rows.

```
static class TestResultToRowConverter extends DoFn<TestResult, TableRow> {
    /**
     * In this example, put the whole string into single BigQuery field.
     */
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      System.out.println("setting TestResult-> TestResult:" + c.element());
      c.output(new TableRow().set("testName", c.element().testName).set("testId", c.element().testId).set("testStatus", c.element().testStatus).set("testResult", c.element().testResult).set("memoryTestData", "example data test"));
      for (Partition pt :  c.element().testPartitions)
      {
        c.output(partitionsTag, new TableRow().set("testId", pt.testId).set("filesystem", pt.filesystem).set("mountedOn", pt.mountedOn).set("usePercentage", pt.usePercentage).set("available", pt.available).set("size", pt.size).set("used", pt.used));
      }
    }
```

And now I want to write them to BigQuery, but the table row of the test result goes to one table with an specific schema and the partitions go to another table with another schema. Also mention that there is an Id that links both and I need to autogenerate when the testResult is added and reused when the partition rows are inserted.

How can I accomplish this?

I was using this for writing to 1 table, but I'm lost if I want to write to two tables.

```
    .apply("MemoryTest_WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(TestResultToRowConverter.getTableSpec1())
        .withSchema(TestResultToRowConverter.getMemoryTestSchema())
        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

EDIT:

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline.apply("ReadFromPubSubToBigQuery_MemoryTest", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromTopic(options.getPubsubTopic()))
    .apply("MemoryTest_ProcessObject", ParDo.of(new ProcessTestResult()))
    .apply("MemoryTest_IdentifyMemoryTest",ParDo.of(new DetectTestType()))
    .apply("MemoryTest_TransformIntoTableRow", ParDo.of(new TestResultToRowConverter()).withOutputTags(partitionsTag))
    .apply("MemoryTest_WriteToBigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(TestResultToRowConverter.getTableSpec1())
        .withSchema(TestResultToRowConverter.getMemoryTestSchema())
        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beam pipelines are not limited to being a single straight line of transforms applied one after another - that would be very restrictive.

You can apply as many transforms as you want to any `PCollection`.

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...;
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(first table));
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(second table));
rows.apply(some more processing)
    .apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(third table));
```

Comment: How can I adapt this to my pipeline? I edited my OP so you can see how it looks.

Comment: Just extract the stuff up until "MemoryTest_TransformIntoTableRow" into a variable of type PCollection<TableRow>.

Comment: Many of the Beam examples pass PCollections to multiple transforms. E.g. see this one https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d13c1feeaeeec4af079f2da523849c218cc50882/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/LeaderBoard.java#L204 : gameEvents is used below to compute both team scores and user scores.